# Printing Request with multipart/form-data using org.zalando.logbook

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, multipartform-data

I want to log the contents of the multipart request with boundries
like

> multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxCgWXWJCGSiUnUwp

which has a json object.

I am using `org.zalando.logbook` in my spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.TraceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.TraceRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * This filter would print the multipart request body except the multipart content. and is given the LOWEST
 * .PRECEDENCE among all the rest of the filters.
 */
@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomWebTraceFilter extends WebRequestTraceFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebTraceFilter.class);

    public CustomWebTraceFilter(TraceRepository repository, TraceProperties properties) {
        super(repository, properties);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the request body if the request has multipart/form-data as content type
     *
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getTrace(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> trace = super.getTrace(request);
                String multipartHeader = request.getHeader("content-type");
        if (!Objects.isNull(multipartHeader) && multipartHeader.startsWith("multipart/form-data")) {
            try {
                request.getParts().forEach(
                        part -> {
                            try {
                                    LOGGER.info("multipart request object :: {}:{}", part.getName(), IOUtils.toString(part.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                LOGGER.error("Exception in Fetching Multi-part Request Object ", e);
                            }
                        }
                );
            } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in Fetching Multi-part Request Object ", e);
            }
        }
        return trace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with Spring 2.1.0

````
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final List<MediaType> VISIBLE_TYPES = Arrays.asList(
        MediaType.valueOf("text/*"),
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
        MediaType.valueOf("application/*+json"),
        MediaType.valueOf("application/*+xml"),
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
        );
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqAndResLoggingFilter.class);
private static final Path path = Paths.get("/home/ramesh/loggerReq.txt");
private static BufferedWriter writer = null;
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    if (isAsyncDispatch(request)) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        doFilterWrapped(wrapRequest(request), wrapResponse(response), filterChain);
    }
    }finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}

protected void doFilterWrapped(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        beforeRequest(request, response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    finally {
        afterRequest(request, response);
        response.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
}

protected void beforeRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) throws IOException {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logRequestHeader(request, request.getRemoteAddr() + "|>");
    }
}

protected void afterRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) throws IOException {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logRequestBody(request, request.getRemoteAddr() + "|>");
        logResponse(response, request.getRemoteAddr() + "|<");
    }
}

private void logRequestHeader(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, String prefix) throws IOException {
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    if (queryString == null) {
        printLines(prefix,request.getMethod(),request.getRequestURI());
        log.info("{} {} {}", prefix, request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
    } else {
        printLines(prefix,request.getMethod(),request.getRequestURI(),queryString);
        log.info("{} {} {}?{}", prefix, request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), queryString);
    }
    Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).forEach(headerName ->
    Collections.list(request.getHeaders(headerName)).forEach(headerValue ->
    log.info("{} {}: {}", prefix, headerName, headerValue)));
    printLines(prefix);
    printLines(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId());
    log.info("{}", prefix);

    log.info(" Session ID: ", RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId());
}

private void printLines(String ...args) throws IOException {

    try {
    for(String varArgs:args) {
            writer.write(varArgs);
            writer.newLine();
    }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void logRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, String prefix) {
    byte[] content = request.getContentAsByteArray();
    if (content.length > 0) {
        logContent(content, request.getContentType(), request.getCharacterEncoding(), prefix);
    }
}

private void logResponse(ContentCachingResponseWrapper response, String prefix) throws IOException {
    int status = response.getStatus();
    printLines(prefix, String.valueOf(status), HttpStatus.valueOf(status).getReasonPhrase());
    log.info("{} {} {}", prefix, status, HttpStatus.valueOf(status).getReasonPhrase());
    response.getHeaderNames().forEach(headerName ->
    response.getHeaders(headerName).forEach(headerValue ->
    log.info("{} {}: {}", prefix, headerName, headerValue)));
    printLines(prefix);
    log.info("{}", prefix);
    byte[] content = response.getContentAsByteArray();
    if (content.length > 0) {
        logContent(content, response.getContentType(), response.getCharacterEncoding(), prefix);
    }
}

private void logContent(byte[] content, String contentType, String contentEncoding, String prefix) {
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.valueOf(contentType);
    boolean visible = VISIBLE_TYPES.stream().anyMatch(visibleType -> visibleType.includes(mediaType));
    if (visible) {
        try {
            String contentString = new String(content, contentEncoding);
            Stream.of(contentString.split("\r\n|\r|\n")).forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    printLines(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
//              log.info("{} {}", prefix, line));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            log.info("{} [{} bytes content]", prefix, content.length);
        }
    } else {

        log.info("{} [{} bytes content]", prefix, content.length);
    }
}

private static ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
        return (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
    } else {
        return new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    }
}

private static ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
        return (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response;
    } else {
        return new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    }
}
}```
````